# RxJS - Observable does not execute when takeUntil and its notifier observable emits in the same internal observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators, takeuntil

Code:

```js
    const main$ = of(true);
    const int$ = interval(2000);
    const notifier$ = new Subject();

    main$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => int$.pipe(
        tap(() => {
          // some logic for when to trigger notifier
          notifier$.next(1); // after some intervals
        }),
        takeUntil(notifier$),
      )),
      tap(() => {// never reach here})
    ).subscribe(() => {
      // never reach here
    });
```

In the above code, `takeUntil` stops the `interval` when the `notifier$` emits but it does not call `subscribe()` ever and never reach the operators eg. `tap()` (see code) after `takeUntil`. Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

the `takeUntil` operator emits the values emitted by a source Observable that would be your `main$` Observable until a notifier Observable emits a value as it is being done by the `notifier$` Subject. Thus, after `notifier$` emits a value on the `next` call within the very first iteration of your interval, the `takeUntil` prevents the underlying Observable to be propagated any further, meaning that the `tap` operator will never be reached.

If you were using a different implementation for your `notifier$` such as `timer`, you could observe the `tap` operator to be called until the timer elapses and thereby triggering the `takeUntil`.

```
    const main$ = of(true);
    const int$ = interval(2000);
    const notifier$ = timer(10000);

    main$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => int$.pipe(
        tap(() => {
          // some logic for when to trigger notifier
        }),
        takeUntil(notifier$),
      )),
      tap((result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
    ).subscribe((result) => {
      // will be reached four times.
    });
   }
```